# Concern of a string conversion function

Tags: c++, string, encoding, utf-8

I made a conversion function from a proprietary text format to a simple text string with escaped unicode codepoints (in the form `\uXXXX' where XXXX is the unicode codepoint in hex format).

```
int wchar_to_utf16(wchar_t* strIn, char* strOut, int max_buf_len);
```

In this function I pass the pointer to the string to be converted, the pointer to the destination buffer (in which the converted string will be written) and the length of such buffer.

Inside the function there are buffer bound checks all over the place, if the space is not enough the function returns 1 otherwise 0.

My question is: is a concern of my function to know the buffer length and perform the checks or it's better to remove the length parameter and do the check on the caller?
Problem:
The minimum buffer length can only be determined looking at the input string and knowing the encoding (which should not be a concern of the caller)

Comment: Is this a big deal? I would go with your current function signature because it helps in the long run.

Comment: not a big deal. just to know. However, since the inner working of the string encoding should not be exposed I'd prefer to go for the solution in which it's the function itself that tell if the space is enough or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is go through the entire input string to determine the required length of the output string, then allocate that amount and then do the conversion. That way, you avoid the need for the caller to specify a "maximum" length, which the caller might guess wrong (then what?). The downside is that you must examine the entire input string twice.

On the other hand, the caller might already know the length in characters of the input string, for example by calling wcslen, and that isn't too much to expect from the caller, so if that information is sufficient for your function then yeah, let the caller provide it, they can calculate it once and keep that number around for whenever they need it again (to avoid going through the whole input string every time). If that information isn't sufficient (I can't tell for sure as I didn't understand the question fully), then don't expect a maximum buffer size because that would expose implementation details (which isn't the case when your function expects the length in characters of a string).

If you are fine with exposing implementation details, then perhaps a maximum buffer size might work, but then again, what would you do if the caller guessed the wrong size? Convert all of it wasting space? Convert a little because the whole thing doesn't fit? If you want a clean interface that hides the implementation, then calculate the buffer size yourself, unless there's any information you can reasonably expect the caller to provide (such as the length of the string).

**Edit:**

What you could do is write a function called, say, `wchar_to_utf16_calc_len` which takes in a `wchar_t *` and calculates the ideal length of the buffer that will store the converted string, without actually allocating anything yet. Then the caller can allocate the buffer with the ideal length and pass the buffer into the conversion function.

This setup requires that the caller know no more about the encoding than is required to use the `wchar_to_utf16` function *and* (correct me if I'm mistaken) removes the need for bounds checking in the conversion function as the buffer will be guaranteed to be big enough (assuming the caller properly remembers to use this length calculation function), *and* you won't have to allocate the buffer inside the conversion function because the caller will know how big of an array to allocate. This removes the need for the length parameter.

Comment: ok to calculate the space inside the function. But this implies I have to allocate the buffer inside the function as well

Comment: My suggestion was for you to _calculate the required space in the function and then allocate the buffer in the function_, rather than to _request a guessed size from outside of the function (as an argument) and then allocate the buffer inside the function with the given size_. In either case, this means that the caller would still be responsible for releasing the dynamically allocated memory. Sorry if I misunderstood something.

Comment: no no it's ok. The problem is that I really don't want to allocate the buffer inside the function and let someone else free it

Comment: I see. The buffer is gonna have to be allocated dynamically 'cause you won't know its size until runtime (I assume), so someone is gonna have to free it, and if it's allocated outside of the function, then you must provide its size somehow, like through an argument. Was your other idea to assume the caller allocated enough space and thus remove the buffer size argument?

Comment: my other idea was to get the caller compute the buffer length but doing it would require it to know too much about the encoding.